# How to check and test if two lines (linear equations) are parallel by throwing an illegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, equation, illegalargumentexception, throw

I'm doing a project at school which one of the methods find the point of intersection of two lines. It substitutes one line’s mx+b value for the other equation’s y values, then it solve for x. I'm trying to set up a "throw" where if the two lines are parallel, it will throw an illegalArgumentException. Here is the method (from the Line class) I'm trying to setup:

```
public Point findIntersect(Line otherLine) {
        double slope2 = otherLine.getSlope();
        double yIntercept2 = otherLine.getIntercept();

        double newX = (intercept - yIntercept2) / (slope2 - slope);
        double newY = slope * newX + intercept;
        Point aPoint = new Point(newX, newY);
        return aPoint;
    }
```

And the method that's being substantiated from:

```
public Point(double x, double y) {
        setLocation (x, y);
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as how to properly do this?

Comment: Don't throw an exception.  That should be reserved for exceptional situations.  I don't think that parallel lines meet that standard.

Comment: What's the return supposed to be for the _same_ line?  The problem here would be there's three types of intersections; no intersection (parallel, but distinct lines), a single point (non-parallel lines), and the whole line (line intersecting with itself).  Returning a `Point` is not always going to suffice.

Comment: I got to throw an illegalArgumentException. The assignment says so: • findIntersect() throws an IllegalArgumentException if the two lines are parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Check if slopes of lines are equal. This indicates that the lines are parallel.

You can have a check similar to this:

```
if(slope == slope2){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Lines are parallel.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this after the first line,

```
if (this.slope == otherLine.getSlope()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parallel lines will never intersect.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not robust to test whether two floating-point values are equal or not. They could be different, yet so close to each other that their difference is very small and you get an overflow to infinity when you carry out the division by this difference.

It will be more useful for most purposes to carry out the computation of `newX` and *then* check whether the value you get is within a reasonable range. In some contexts it is better to just check whether it is infinite.

```
 if( Double.isNaN(new X) ) {
     // This happens when we divide 0 by 0
     // The lines are the same line, so there are many intersections
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("The intersection is not unique.");
 }
 if( Double.isInfinite(newX) ) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("These line are parallel or almost so.");
 }
```